# ASP.NET HyperLink - Setting Alt tag of the Image

Tags: asp.net

How can I set the alt tag of an image that has been set using `HyperLink.ImageUrl`? I read an article that states you should be able to do `HyperLink.Attributes["text"] = "My Alt Text"` but that doesn't seem to work.

I want to try and avoid creating a separate image control and adding it to that hyperlink just to set an Alt tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

asp:Hyperlink already has a "Text" property. Just set it and that will serve as the alt property of the image if you have the ImageUrl set.

ETA: I haved edited my answer based on Andrew MacNeill's suggestion below to show some example code.

Example:

```
hyperLink.Text = "My Alt Text"; 
hyperLink.NaviateURL = "www.myurl.com";
hyperLink.ImageURL = "myimage.jpg";
```

Renders HTML as:

```
<a href="www.myurl.com">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" title="My Alt text" alt="My Alt Text">
    </img>
</a>
```

Comment: @Freakishly  
This works perfectly for me with an Image Hyperlink by either setting the properties in the markup or the code behind. Please post your code.  We are talking about the alt text attribute for the image, not the title attribute. Please see my comment and code under your answer. Inspect the page element with Firebug or developer tools in Chrome or IE and see how the element is rendered with a separate title attribute for the ToolTip property and an alt attribute from the Text property.

Comment: @Freakishly  A downvote, really? I don't think your code is correct.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and I wish this was marked as the Answer as this is a far easier method to implement. I would suggest showing code and output as an example as it would make it much clearer than the other two mechanisms. Something like  

`HyperLink.Text = "My Alt Text"   HyperLink.NaviateURL = "www.google.com"  HyperLink.ImageURL = "myimage.jpg"  `

translates into  


`<a href="www.google.com"> <img src="myimage.jpg" title="My Alt text" alt="My Alt Text"></img></a>`

Comment: @AndrewMacNeill Updated the selected answer. It came in a year after I asked it so didn't pay much attention :)

Answer (score 1):

it could work with the Attributes as you have mentioned but you should set such attribute in the PreRender event of the page or of the HyperLink, if you set it before the PreRender you will most likely lose it.

Comment: I am currently doing it in the Page_Load() event so I presume that is causing the issue. Is this the only / reccommended way to do it?

Comment: Hi, it's probably not the only one but the most used because PreRender happens right before the render and it's the last place where you have the chance to change the attributes being sure nobody/nothing else will touch the page again, except of course some javascript code but that's not your case.

Comment: no problem, please mark the question as answered if my post has solved your issue.

Comment: Was going to but it wouldn't let me for another 4 minutes :)

Answer (score -2):

From codebehind, you can use something like this:

```
HyperLink HyperLink1 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1");
HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "Images\\Success.png";
HyperLink1.ToolTip = "Completed";
```

The ToolTip property will map to the alternate text for the image.

Comment: Tooltip won't set the alternate text only the hover tooltip. The alternate text can be controlled by setting the Text of the Hyperlink in either the markup such as <asp:Hyperlink>Alt Text</asp:Hyperlink> or in the code behind.

`HyperLink1.ToolTip = "Tooltip Text";  
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";  
HyperLink1.Text = "Alt Text";  
HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "~/MyImage.jpg";`